# Why is gedit not populating the Open Recent files menu option on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gedit

It seems to have stopped working for me on 16.04, updated to latest versions.

I can open and save a file with a name but then the gedit menu open recent doesn't show it or any other ones I have opened or edited.  Just has Reopen Closed Tab in gray.

[image]

Interestingly... the 'open' button *does* present my recent files, something I haven't seen before today

[image]

Running `$/usr/bin/gedit` works does bring up `gedit` (still with the issue), although this way I do get the following warning

```
(gedit:17233): Gtk-WARNING **:  
Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:25: Missing name of pseudo-class
```

Comment: Did you happen to run gedit as root recently?

Comment: Or change some Files & Applications  settings in Security & Privacy?

Comment: I did neither of the above

Comment: I am beginning to believe this might have something to do with running gedit with sudo.

Comment: I also have run gedit from the command line (no sudo) and also saved files using this method but the problem is the same.

Comment: I increased the amount of recent files shown with the *open* button using `$ gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents 10`. (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a confirmed issue that manifests with GEdit, Gnome and Ubuntu combination. Here is a link to the bug -
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1570227

I do realize that this is not an answer but I can't really add a comment to the question due to lack on enough points, which is why this "answer".

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Mint 18.1, but it's based on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I found this question, I wasn't even getting the recent files in the Open/ menu.  It appears that the gedit developers are planning to move to that way of displaying recent files.  However, I wasn't getting recent files in GIMP either, but I found some information that explains why.

#### Solution

Look under *Preferences → System Settings → Privacy* for the option to *Remember recently accessed files*. After enabling that, I get my document histories in the Ubuntu based applications again.

Comment: I am trying to follow your answer to this issue with gedit, I am experiencing same as OP no recent files in gedit open menu.  I cannot find System Settings under/in the gedit nor GIMP Preferences popup.  I wonder if you could edit it your solution to include more details for me.  Thank you :)

Comment: This helped me. I recently installed cinnamon in Ubuntu 19.04 and my recent files went away in gedit. I found this "Remember recently accessed files" option and turned it on, and then it started working again.

Comment: It helped me with Mint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a system-wide issue, not directly caused by gnome packages. I have actually first noticed it with mousepad (part of xfce wm) after Linux Mint 18.1 system upgrade. Gedit was also affected by same update.

Only mentioning this since the gedit bug mentioned above concerns a newer ubuntu version.

Regardless of version you should first check gedit's hidden preferences with dconf (or dconf-editor) here: org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui.max-recents

example reading max-recents value using dconf:

```
    dconf read /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/ui/max-recents
```

you can also change the same value, ex.:

```
    dconf write /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/ui/max-recents "uint32 40"
```