# Is it possible to bring back the search box in gedit open recent files dropdown in 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gedit

After upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 I noticed that there is no longer a handy search box when I try to open a recent file. Only a dropdown of the last 10 opened files (as shown in the image).

[image: Image from https://askubuntu.com/questions/888984/why-is-gedit-not-populating-the-open-recent-files-menu-option-on-16-04]

Is it possible to bring the old drop down back? If yes, how?

Comment: I miss it too. I've been lookin everywhere, the official plugins, the third party plugins, and found nothing. My guess is that it's just gone...

Comment: There's a 'quick open' plugin that has a search box *on* 18.04 and version 3.28.1. I have no idea what it's like on 20.04, but you can check. It's one extra click - if it does exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [KGIII said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285616/is-it-possible-to-bring-back-the-search-box-in-gedit-open-recent-files-dropdown#comment2181825_1285616), there is a *Quick Open* plugin for gedit, that also works in Ubuntu 20.04.

To enable the plugin click the hamburger menu (the button with the three lines on the top right) → *Preferences* → *Plugins* and enable *Quick Open* (see screenshot below).

[image: Enable Quick Open]

After that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open a window which shows your recently opened files but also allows to search for files to open.

[image: Quick Open]

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't anywhere near my computer with a 20.04 VM to check if it was the same on newer versions, and I use an older Lubuntu LTS as my daily driver. So it's great that it works and that you were able to resolve it for them.

Comment: @KGill I should thank you! I just tried out what you suggested in your comment.

Comment: I accepted this answer since it's good enough workaround/replacement, although not as convenient as the original feature was (so If anyone finds a way to restore the original UI, they are welcome to post it as an answer).